# Python Threading with varying arguments (Python 2.4.3)

Tags: python, multithreading, centos, python-multithreading

I am learning the threading and concurrency part in python, and I choose an example where I do an `os.walk()` to get a list of files from a directory, populate it to an array using `os.path.join()` and then use threading to change ownership of these files. The purpose of this script is to learn threading. My code is

```
for root, dir, file in os.walk("/tmpdir/"):
    for name in file:
        files.append(os.path.join(root, name))

def filestat(file):
    print file ##The code to chown will go here. Writing it to just print the file for now.

thread = [threading.Thread(target=filestat, args="filename") for x in range(len(files))]
print thread ##This will give me the total number of thread objects that is created
for t in thread:
    t.start() ##This will start the thread execution
```

This will print the "filename" when executed for `len(files)` times. However, I wanted to pass the filename inside the list files as the argument to the function. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the variable name you're iterating over inside the `args` argument. Don't forget to make it a tuple.

```
thread = [threading.Thread(target=filestat, args=(files[x],)) for x in range(len(files))]
```

Or

```
thread = [threading.Thread(target=filestat, args=(filename,)) for filename in files]
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. So what would be the number of threads or concurrency used in this program?

Comment: One for each file name.

Comment: What should I modify in this program, if I want to increase the concurrency to `x` number?